# VKapi как в консоли ввести капчу 14. Captcha needed

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, captcha

Используя метод [photos.edit](https://vk.com/dev/photos.edit) изменяю описание к фотографиям примерно на 20й возникает ошибка **14. Captcha needed** использую try

```
try:
   vkapi.photos.edit(
      photo_id=myphoto_id,
      caption=texts
    )
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   time.sleep(5)
```

словарь содержит следующие:

> 14. Captcha needed. request_params = {'caption': 'vk.com/wall376851223_3941\nРљРѕР¶Р° РЅР°С‚СѓСЂР°Р»СЊРЅС‹Р№\nР¦РµРЅР° 1700 СЂ.......', 'oauth': '1', 'method': 'photos.edit', 'photo_id': '45.......', 'v': '5.62'}

а описание [Ошибка с Captcha](https://vk.com/dev/captcha_error) указаны другие поля. Возможно ли из консоли вывести картинку с капчей и ввести ее? например при помощи библиотеке pillow

Comment: "в консоли" если и возможно, то крайне сложно, а вот открыть окно браузера с капчей вполне возможно

Comment: конечно не "в консоли" это опечатка, исправил.